# How can i make two images blend together with css?

Tags: css, reactjs

This is how my website looks:
[image]

As you can see there is quite a harsh line between the two images, I want the two images to overlap a little bit and lower the opacity on the edge of each image so that they blend together, I can't find a good way to solve this.

Here are my classes for the two images,

Left image:

```css
.landingLeagueDivImage {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.landingLeagueDivImage::before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top -5vh right -15vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(./images/riven.webp);
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Right image:

```css
.landingCs2DivImage {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  position: relative;
}

.landingCs2DivImage::before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top -5vh left 35vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(./images/cs2bg2.webp);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered HTML canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the CSS for the `::before` pseudo-elements of both images.

```
.landingLeagueDivImage::before {
  content: "";
  top: -10px; /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  left: -10px; /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  width: calc(100% + 20px); /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  height: calc(100% + 20px); /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), url(./images/riven.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top -5vh right -15vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.landingCs2DivImage::before {
  content: "";
  top: -10px; /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  right: -10px; /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  width: calc(100% + 20px); /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  height: calc(100% + 20px); /* Adjust as needed to overlap */
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), url(./images/cs2bg2.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top -5vh left 35vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```